# How to Create an Activity with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm new to android, so this may also seem like a dumb question.  I have a listview and I populated it with some data via an adapter.  However, I tried to use the code for the clickItem method, but I get red squiggly lines.  All I want is for when someone clicks one of the items in a list view, it will play a song.

Here is the code:

```
package com.juwar74.alarabic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class OneExp extends ActionBarActivity 
{
     private ListView lv; 
     private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.one_exp);

         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

         List<String> Exp_list = new ArrayList<String>();
         Exp_list.add("Hello.");
         Exp_list.add("How are you?");
         Exp_list.add("I'm fine.");
         Exp_list.add("Thank you.");
         Exp_list.add("My name is...");
         Exp_list.add("Nice to meet you.  Please call me...");
         Exp_list.add("What's your name?");
         Exp_list.add("Good Morning.");
         Exp_list.add("Good Evening.");
         Exp_list.add("You're welcome.");
         Exp_list.add("Good bye.");

         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Exp_list);
         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new .OnItemClickListener() 
         {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) 
             {
                 arrayAdapter = ...;
             }
         }); 
     }
}
```

The red squiggly lines are at the setOnItemClick and the .OnItemClick. It seems like the most basic operations are the hardest to find on the internet.  All the sites I go to will show you how to set up a listview, but they don't go beyond that.  No one really teaches how to interact with the listview in details....Strange.

Comment: I don't know what you searched for but I have no problem finding tutorials on how to interact with a listview ... http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html or another (bit more fancy) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: `(new .OnItemClickListener()` is not valid Java syntax

Answer (score 0):

Do your stuff based on position

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
             if(position==0){
                //first position, use intent to play your song
                Toast.makeText(OneExp.this,"First position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                }
             });
```